# JQuery: Extracting Int from JSON always returns NaN

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to extract the x an y values of a JSON object.

This is my raw JSON as extracted from my debugger:

```
"[{\"x\":10,\"y\":10},{\"x\":20,\"y\":10},{\"x\":70,\"y\":10},{\"x\":80,\"y\":10},{\"x\":90,\"y\":10}]"
```

Here is my code to process it

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dataPoints = [];

    $.getJSON("/Home/GetData/", function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
            dataPoints.push({ x: parseInt(data[i].x), y: parseInt(data[i].y) });
        }

    });

});
```

Each element is processed to dataPoints as expected BUT all values contain NANs and not the value expected.

Comment: Use a debugger an examine the structure of "data" as returned from the Ajax call.  What does it look like?

Comment: The data pasted above under "This is my raw JSON" IS from my debugger. It is exactly what my script is trying to process.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/h1tsmdjx/ . It works fine. Seems the elements of the array are strings to be parse.

Comment: Hi Luca read others comments. I was trying to parse a string not a JSON object so there was an issue.

Comment: Looking the answers below, I should just mention that you don't need to use `$.parseJSON` when using `$.getJSON` because the callback is doing it automatically. Maybe your resource is not sending a `JSON` object. That's the issue. The solution is either to fix the resource to send `JSON` or not use `$.getJSON` but a regular `$.get`.

Comment: Not entirely sure why this was voted down. I did research. Posted full code and attempted to debug myself posting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 
`jQuery.parseJSON()` around you result data

Like this:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetData/", function (data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        dataPoints= data;
    });
```

But you really should make sure that your service returns the result as Json instead of a string

Comment: Thank you! Accepted. Amir was first but your solution is cleaner.

Comment: That for loop is redundant OP, JSON.parse generate an object already.

Comment: True that will change it

Answer (score 1):

You have a json string and you will need to parse it into a json and then work on numbers:

```
var str = "[{\"x\":10,\"y\":10},{\"x\":20,\"y\":10},{\"x\":70,\"y\":10},{\"x\":80,\"y\":10},{\"x\":90,\"y\":10}]";

console.log(str[0]); // [
console.log(str[1]); // {
var json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json[0].x);
```

Your code:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetData/", function (data) {
       var jsData = json.Parse(data); // parse here...
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
            dataPoints.push({ x: parseInt(jsData[i].x), y: parseInt(jsData[i].y) });
        }

 });
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvfrn9uz/).

Comment: Exactly right. 

Lack of comprehension on my part I thought it was parsing a Json object not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You retrieved the JSON BUT you don't need to create your own parsing function:

```
var dataPoints = [];
var test = "[{\"x\":10,\"y\":10},{\"x\":20,\"y\":10},{\"x\":70,\"y\":10},{\"x\":80,\"y\":10},{\"x\":90,\"y\":10}]";
var data = JSON.parse(test);

data
[Object { x=10, y=10}, Object { x=20, y=10}, Object { x=70, y=10}, Object { x=80, y=10}, Object { x=90, y=10}]

data[0]['x']
10
```